# Adding new menu items for different document types

Tags: document-library, ribbon

How can I add new menu items to New Item menu of document libraries? I want to add "New Powerpoint File" option to the menu so that users create PowerPoint documents just like they create Word files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this article - http://blog.sharepointdevelopment.nl/post/How-to-get-Excel-and-Powerpoint-Button-under-New-Button-in-SharePoint-Document-Library.aspx